# Is it possible to build a server array

Tags: web-server, raid, configuration

I am researching a  redundant server system,
And i came with the following question:
Is it possible to build multiple server s in a raid 1 configuration (like hard drives).

This because if one server fails the application cannot go offline and won't lose any data at all.

It is very important that i do not lose any data,
This because the data (when the system is being used) is from a live sport event,
And needs to be saved for later research and is being used for a live display on a web site.

The data is coming in from GPS trackers.

I tried to search on the forum but i could not find any information about a server configuration in raid (or something alike).

Comment: Start searching for High Availability. Be prepared to read for a few days though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually called *High Availability* or *fail-over*.  And yes, it's possible.  Many companies do it, and depending on your approach (and your definition of not losing any data at all) it can even be pretty cheap and easy.

Of course, the lack of specifics in your questions kind of limits the information you can expect in an answer, but if you try searching on the terms above, you should be able to find the information you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Only solution I am aware of that would do that *completely* without any intelligence in the server OS/application stack required would be something VMWare FT-based ....